# Sequelize hasOne include not working properly

Tags: sql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js, sql-limit

I am trying to include `hasOne` association with `findAll` method
like below

```
await db.Symbol.findAll({
    where:{
        symbol: symbols
    },
    attributes: ['symbol'],
    include: [{
        as: 'price',
        model: db.Price,
        attributes: ['adjClose', 'createdAt']
    }]
});
```

but I got wrong result, because sequelize giving me result like below.

```
{ 
  symbol: 'SNAP',
  price: { adjClose: 22.07, createdAt: 2017-03-10T00:00:00.000Z } 
},
{ 
  symbol: 'SNAP',
  price: { adjClose: 22.709999, createdAt: 2017-03-09T00:00:00.000Z } 
}
```

but I need only one object , because I have include my hasOne assocation as `price` and don't need duplicated values of my 'symbol' object.

my `hasOne` association looks like this

```
Symbol.hasOne(models.Price,{
    as: "price",
    foreignKey:"companyId"
});
```

Is there a way to select only one item with include?
I nee just limit in subquery which I guess can help, but as I know unfortunately 
sequelize doesn't support it.

Hope someone can help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you expect to receive symbol with all it's prices as a single object, or you just want to limit the result you already have to single object?

Comment: I just want to get symbol with only one last price

Comment: Please note that `symbols` variable in first code block is array of symbols, since in my request I will need last prices of few symbols